# Unable to import pandas using Python 3.8 because this is already installed for Anaconda

Tags: python, pandas, import, anaconda

I am running Python 3.8 and I am unable to import pandas. Pandas is already installed but this is for Anaconda.

Can someone be very kind to help?

Thank you so much

Comment: You installed pandas in your Conda environment and you can't import it? Or you installed pandas globally and can't import it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the details you had given, you had installed Pandas for Anaconda. So, pandas installed in the conda environment and if you want to use pandas outside the conda environment then you have to install the pandas library globally.

Go to your regular command line/terminal and install pandas globally using the following command.

```
$ pip3 install pandas
```

After doing this you can use pandas from anywhere in your current system/OS.